# Null Pointer Error Due To Initializing Spring Java Based Direct Injection

Tags: java, spring, selenium-webdriver, nullpointerexception, initialization

I know the null pointer error is because the injection isn't getting initialized correctly. Not exactly sure how to fix it.

I've got three files: the main (CommonElements.java), Constructor.java (the bean), and Driver.java (where the main code is).

Trying to get driver.java injected into commomelements and when it is run, that's when the null pointer exception occurs.

Here's the code for each. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

CommonElements.java

```
package PageFactory;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;

public class CommonElements {

private Driver web;

    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Constructor.class);      
    Driver page = ctx.getBean(Driver.class); 

    @Test
    public void Common(final Driver web)
    {
        this.web = web;
        web.setup();
    }
}
```

Constructor.java

```
package PageFactory;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;

//constructor 
@Configuration //using java dependency injection
public class Constructor {
    @Bean
    public Driver driver() {
        return new Driver();
    }

}
```

Driver.java

```
package PageFactory;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class Driver {

    private String baseUrl;

    public void setup() {
        final WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
        "drivers/chromedriver.exe"); //location of driver
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        baseUrl = "https://www.google.com";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? Also, have you stepped through your code using a debugger?

Comment: It won't even run the debugger.  This is what it says:

Launching CommentElemetns has encountered a problem:

An internal error occurred during: "Launching CommonElements (1)".
java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

edit: i'm not sure junit is able to inject the Driver bean in your test method, can you try something like this

```
package PageFactory;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;

public class CommonElements {

private Driver web;

    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Constructor.class);      
    Driver page = ctx.getBean(Driver.class); 

    @Test
    public void Common()
    {
        page.setup();
    }
}
```

also since you are initializing manually the spring context you probably don't need what i suggested below

old answer:

I think you need to add this annotation to the test class if you want junit to initialize spring

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration // i'm not 100% sure this one is needed 
public class CommonElements {
 ...
}
```

reference: [link](https://dzone.com/articles/junit-testing-spring-mvc-1)

Comment: hmmm, that did not seem to work either, thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Ah...I don't have a getDriver() or setDriver() method. That may help...

Comment: mh i noticed that your are somehow trying to let junit inject your bean in the test method, i have never seen it used like that, i would try to remove the driver parameter and just do page.setup() in your test
i'm editing the answer to show the code